# 2 cards independence and dependence

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, independence

Needing help with one more question on independent and dependent events when drawing 2 cards without replacement. How do you determine whether events H=first card is a heart and F=second card is face card are independent or dependent?

Answer (score 1):

If H happens, then $\frac{10}{13}$ of the time there will be $12$ face cards remaining (because the heart drawn was not a face card) and $\frac{3}{13}$ of the time there will be $12$ face cards remaining.

If H does not happen then $\frac{30}{39}$ of the time there will be $12$ face cards remaining (because the heart drawn was not a face card) and $\frac{9}{39}$ of the time there will be $12$ face cards remaining.

These are identical situations (because $\frac{10}{13}=\frac{30}{39}$) and therefore F is independent of H.

Comment: I think you mean "$11$ face cards remaining" two places.

Comment: I am sorry but I am still confused. Is there a tree that can be drawn to illustrate what is going on and can clear the calculations up for me? I totally understand the formulas but don't quite get how to calculate the probability of getting face card on second draw, denoted P(F) =  P(F|H)